# Lubridate: Intervals that overlaps any other by group

Tags: intervals, lubridate, overlapping

Hello and Thank you so much!

I'm trying to identify which intervals overlaps any other in a group.

For instance, If we had the following data:

```
id <- rep(1:3, each=3)
hospitalization <- seq(ymd_hms("2017-11-28 00:00:01"), by = "day", length.out = length(id))

dat <- data.frame(id, hospitalization)

dat[3,2] <- dat[3,2] + dhours(12)

library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

dat %>% 
  mutate(
    discharge = hospitalization + dhours(35),
    interval= hospitalization %--% discharge
  ) -> dat

dat

> dat
  id     hospitalization           discharge                                           interval
1  1 2017-11-28 00:00:01 2017-11-29 11:00:01 2017-11-28 00:00:01 UTC--2017-11-29 11:00:01 UTC
2  1 2017-11-29 00:00:01 2017-11-30 11:00:01 2017-11-29 00:00:01 UTC--2017-11-30 11:00:01 UTC
3  1 2017-11-30 12:00:01 2017-12-01 23:00:01 2017-11-30 12:00:01 UTC--2017-12-01 23:00:01 UTC
4  2 2017-12-01 00:00:01 2017-12-02 11:00:01 2017-12-01 00:00:01 UTC--2017-12-02 11:00:01 UTC
5  2 2017-12-02 00:00:01 2017-12-03 11:00:01 2017-12-02 00:00:01 UTC--2017-12-03 11:00:01 UTC
6  2 2017-12-03 00:00:01 2017-12-04 11:00:01 2017-12-03 00:00:01 UTC--2017-12-04 11:00:01 UTC
7  3 2017-12-04 00:00:01 2017-12-05 11:00:01 2017-12-04 00:00:01 UTC--2017-12-05 11:00:01 UTC
8  3 2017-12-05 00:00:01 2017-12-06 11:00:01 2017-12-05 00:00:01 UTC--2017-12-06 11:00:01 UTC
9  3 2017-12-06 00:00:01 2017-12-07 11:00:01 2017-12-06 00:00:01 UTC--2017-12-07 11:00:01 UTC

dat[1,4]
dat[2,4]
dat[3,4]

int_overlaps(dat[1,4],dat[2,4])
int_overlaps(dat[2,4],dat[3,4])
int_overlaps(dat[1,4],dat[3,4])
int_overlaps(dat[1,4],dat[3,4])
```

I would like to calculate a column that is Boolean (`overlap_any`) indicating if a period overlaps any (not all but at least one) another in the same group.

When grouping by id, for `id==1` the first and second periods overlap but they don't with the third one. So for that id `overlap_any` should be `(True,True,False)`.

I was thinking of something like:

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(
    overlap_any = some_function(interval)
  )
```

But I don't know what to do because `group_by` takes all the intervals for a group and not the current line that I would like to evaluate for overlapping with the rest. Furthermore, `int_overlaps` only takes two arguments.

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I did

```
overlaps_others <- function(y) sapply(y, function(x) sum(int_overlaps(x,y)))-1

dat %>% 
  split(id) %>% 
  lapply(function(z){
    z %>% 
      mutate(
        overlaps = overlaps_others(interval)

      ) %>%
      select(-interval)
  }) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

Comment: I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46240252/lubridate-counting-overlapping-intervals-for-every-interval?rq=1)